# i couldnt find code for reading a excel file into pyspark dataframe

Tags: excel, dataframe, record, pyspark

when I m converting excel into csv .. I could find mismatch of records uploaded.

I have xslx file 91800 records but when reading into pyspark dataframe  after converting into csv file it is showing me 92301 records. every operations is working fine but records differs.
can anyone help me?

Comment: Show what you have coded so far then people may help. Or, look for other questions with answers that may help start your code, but this is not a free coding service.

Comment: I m adding one more point.. Cant we directly read the excel file into pyspark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try reading with `Pandas` and then convering to spark dataframe. In my experience, `Pandas` csv read is more stable.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('path')
df_spark = spark.createDataFrame(df)
```

Your number of records seems suitable to read with `Pandas`

Comment: Thanks assaf for ur early reply. But I just want to confirm that .. is this the only ?

Comment: @srilu10 reading CSV with spark sometimes creates issues like you described. Reading excel file regularly (without converting to CSV) is not trivial, but this link might be useful for you - 
https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/22736/is-there-any-way-to-read-xlsx-file-in-pysparkalso-want-to-read-strings-of-colum

Answer (score 0):

In my experience this problem can arise when you have free text fields in your table that contain the delimiter (e.g. comma) and/or new line.

You can resolve that by:

- Choosing the "Quote all text cells" option when exporting the excel file to csv.
- Using the multiLine option when reading in the csv-file to Spark, like `spark.read.csv(file, multiLine=True)`.

Comment: thanks Gerold Busch for ur earliest reply.. but where do I find that "Quote all text cells" in excel while saving it.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://superuser.com/questions/130592/how-do-you-force-excel-to-quote-all-columns-of-a-csv-file